# I want to find out the percentage of HTTPS requests that take less than a second in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have written a JMeter test plan firing HTTPS requests at a web service.  I need to know the percentage of calls that take less than a second.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two plugins/listeners that will generate this directly within JMeter UI or write the files to results if you are doing distributed test.  Both are from the [Extras Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasSet/).

- [Response Times Percentiles](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RespTimePercentiles/) 
  [image]
  The test I am using is simple and the response time is in ms.  Y-axis is milliseconds, and X-Axis is percentage of requests responding in that time.
- [Response Times Distribution](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RespTimesDistribution/)
  Same concept except Y-Axis is number of requests responding in that bucket, X-Axis the response time in milliseconds.  The size of the distribution is configurable.

[image]

Plugin installation is described [here](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/), it is as simple as copying files into your JMeter installation.