# Timeout of JMS Point-to-point requests in JMeter does not result in an error

Tags: jmeter

We are using Apache JMeter 2.12 in order to measure the response time of our JMS queue. However, we would like to see how many of those requests take less than a certain time. This, according to the official site of JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) should be set by the Timeout property. You can see in the photo below how our configuration looks like:
[image: JMS Point-to-point Configration]

However, setting the timeout does not result in an error after sending 100 requests. We can see that some of them take apparently more than that amount of time:

[image: Result]
Is there some other setting I am missing or is there a way to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMeter documentation for [JMS Point-to-Point](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point) describes the timeout as

> The timeout in milliseconds for the reply-messages. If a reply has not been received within the specified time, the specific testcase failes and the specific reply message received after the timeout is discarded. Default value is 2000 ms.

This is timing not the actual sending the message but receipt of a response.

The [source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/dd30d6171d031d3288c7d31da303823dccee03c2/src/protocol/jms/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jms/sampler/JMSSampler.java#L373) for the JMeter Point to Point will determine if you have a 'Receive Queue' Configured.   If you do it will go through the executor path and use the timeout value, otherwise it does not use time timeout value.

```
            if (useTemporyQueue()) {
                executor = new TemporaryQueueExecutor(session, sendQueue);
            } else {
                producer = session.createSender(sendQueue);
                executor = new FixedQueueExecutor(producer, getTimeoutAsInt(), isUseReqMsgIdAsCorrelId());
            }
```

In your screen shot JNDI name Receive Queue is not defined, thus it uses temporary queue, and does not use the timeout.  Should or should not timeout be supported in this case, that is best discussed in JMeter forum.

Alternately if you want to see request times in percentiles/buckets please read this stack overflow Q/A - 
[I want to find out the percentage of HTTPS requests that take less than a second in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582521/i-want-to-find-out-the-percentage-of-https-requests-that-take-less-than-a-second/28585915#28585915)